# How to call vb function from javascript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using textbox (txtFileType) with event OnFocus=("this.blur();"), so I can't use textchanged event for this textbox, I have written a vb code to calculate my FileNumber using stored procedures based on the value of textbox (txtFileType).

Can I call this vb code from javascript which can be used in clientside.. please help with an example.. or any other possible ways..

Answer (score 1):

i assume your vb code is going to reside on the server side. you can expose the server side method as a service and invoke it using javascript. For ajax purpose you can probably look at [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/ExposingWebServicesToAJAXTutorial.aspx) from Microsoft itself.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to call a web service method through your page to process.  Try [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14610/Calling-Web-Services-from-HTML-Pages-using-JavaScr) and let me know if it helps.